# Unable to pass Consumer<> instance

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have a class for walking a directory tree and performing an action on each file/directory.  It looks like this:

```java
class DirWalker {
  public static void walkDirs(Path startingPath, Consumer<Path> vAction)  {...}
}
```

In another class I have the following:

```java
public static Consumer<Path> doVisit = p -> {...}
```

I tried to use this in my Java code like this:

```java
DirWalker.walkDirs(/* a path */, MyClass::doVisit);
```

However, I get an error here saying that 'MyClass does not define doVisit(Path) that is applicable here'.  I can change the `doVisit` member to a method and it works.

If I were to use a lambda inline in the `walkDirs` call it would work fine.  But creating an instance of a `Consumer` and passing that to the `walkDirs` method fails.  Why is this the case?

Comment: `MyClass::doVisit` is a *method* reference but `doVisit` is not a method. Did you mean `MyClass.doVisit`?

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  This is the problem with using multiple languages at the same time.  You tend to mix up the small syntax differences.  I forgot that static fields and methods have a different access syntax in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the method reference syntax (`MyClass::doVisit`) only if doVisit was a method. As you're declaring it, doVisit is a field, and should be accessed as `MyClass.doVisit`

If you want to use the method reference syntax, you can write it as a method that satisfies the `Consumer<Path>` interface instead of an inline lambda expression, like below

```java
public static void doVisit(Path p) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had originally started with a member method but wanted to try changing it to a field and that was where I ran into problems.  I had forgotten about the difference in syntax for accessing static member methods and fields.  Too much C++, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Your `doVisit` is an instance of a `Consumer`. So you cannot use a method reference. Just pass the reference to your `walkDirs` method.

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MyClass {
    public static Consumer<Path> doVisit = path -> {};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirWalker.walkDirs(Path.of("/tmp"), doVisit); // Static
    }

    public static class DirWalker {
        public static void walkDirs(Path startingPath, Consumer<Path> vAction)  {

        }
    }
}
```

If you want to reference the field, use `instance.doVisit`:

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MyClass {
    public Consumer<Path> doVisit = path -> {};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        DirWalker.walkDirs(Path.of("/tmp"), instance.doVisit); // Instance
    }

    public static class DirWalker {
        public static void walkDirs(Path startingPath, Consumer<Path> vAction)  {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a variation of the first, with an additional wrapping class:

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirWalker.walkDirs(Path.of("/tmp"), MyClass.doVisit); // Static
    }

    public static class MyClass {
        public static Consumer<Path> doVisit = path -> {};
    }

    public static class DirWalker {
        public static void walkDirs(Path startingPath, Consumer<Path> vAction)  {

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is a version that I think you are requesting. Create a class called `MyVisitor` with a `doVisit(path: Path): void` method.

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirWalker.walkDirs(Path.of("/tmp"), MyVisitor::doVisit);
    }

    public static class MyVisitor {
        public static void doVisit(Path path) {
            // Print path
        }
    }

    public static class DirWalker {
        public static void walkDirs(Path startingPath, Consumer<Path> vAction)  {
            vAction.accept(startingPath); // Start traversal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The one wrinkle here is that I have three classes involved.  DirWalker, MyClass, and a third class which puts the two together.  So I needed to refer to the static field/method from another class.

Comment: @melston understood, I added two more variations.